# CSS styling constraints for kindle e-ink reader

Tags: html, css, epub, kindle

I am doing some ebook processing. Which involves styling for kindle ebooks. 
It all looks nice while the newer devices are used, but whenever I open an ebook in older kindle e-ink some styles are not set.
Sample:

```
.bordered-box{
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #000000;
}
```

This style is seen fine on kindle-fire and kindle paperwhite, but it is not applied on regular kindle and kindle dx.

Is there any list of constraints and styles that could be applied to those older versions?

PS. Answering a coomment below, here to make it more visible.
The mobis are generated form epubs, that are generated from HTML. So the process is HTML->epub->mobi

Comment: Are you using HTML and kindlegen to create mobis? Just curious which tools you're using.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The older Kindles (and their mobipocket fileformat renderer) does not support those CSS properties.

[Here (PDF link) you can find](http://kindleformatting.com/book/files/KindleHTMLtags.pdf) the standard supported tags/CSS properties. And [here is a nice](http://bbebooksthailand.com/bb-CSS-boilerplate.html) commonly used CSS template.

I would recommend to read through [the official publishing guidelines](http://kindlegen.s3.amazonaws.com/AmazonKindlePublishingGuidelines.pdf) too.

Comment: that was just what I was looking for on that pdf you shared.